# How to create raster layer of frequency of column values in a raster brick/stack

Tags: r, raster, terra

reprex below shows a simple raster brick and using the calc function to return a raster layer showing the layer number with the max for that column.

I want to be able to return a raster layer showing number of times each column exceeds a value e.g. 1

```
library(raster)

## generate simple raster brick
r1 <- r2 <- r3 <- r4 <- r5 <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
r1[] <- rnorm(ncell(r1), 1, 0.2)
r2[] <- rnorm(ncell(r2), 1, 0.2)
r3[] <- rnorm(ncell(r3), 1, 0.2)
r4[] <- rnorm(ncell(r4), 1, 0.2)
r5[] <- rnorm(ncell(r5), 1, 0.2)

s <- brick(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5)

## find which layer the max value occurs
s_max <- calc(s, which.max)

plot(s_max)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sum(s > 1)`. Here illustrated with "terra" (the replacement of "raster")

```
library(terra)
s <- rast(ncol=10, nrow=10, nlyr=5)
set.seed(0)
values(s) <- rnorm(size(s), 1, 0.2)

x <- sum(s > 1)
x
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#source(s)   : memory
#name        : sum 
#min value   :   0 
#max value   :   5
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty close to what you are looking for. You just need to mask the values you are not interested in and reclassify the ones you are interested in as 1. Then you can just sum the values.

```
library(raster)
# set NA to all values that DO NOT exceed 1
s[s<1] <- NA
# set 1 to all values that exceed 1
s[s>=1] <- 1
# Sum them
s_sum <- calc(s, function(x) sum(x, na.rm = T))
```